# Is it mandatory to use AEC qualified component in automotive applications?

Tags: safety, automotive

I'm wondering if it's mandatory to use AEC qualified components in an automotive application. Is it restricted to safety related applications?

I talked to a more experienced engineer about some capacitors an he seems to accept Y (non AEC qualified) capacitor in automobile. I find this very confusing.

Also, is it ok to use medical or military in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is AEC ?

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automotive_Electronics_Council):

*The Automotive Electronics Council (AEC) is an organisation based in the United States that sets qualification standards for the supply of components in the automotive electronics industry.*

So the AEC only **sets the standards**.

Let's imagine a silly example:

AEC standard 12345A specifies that capacitors need to have a colour.

So does this mean that the AEC will sue you if you use Black capacitors (assuming that black is not a colour) in your product for the Automotive market ?

**No** because the AEC only writes that document, it does not check (or even care) that you use black capacitors.

Only if you are going to sell your product to a car manufacturer that manufacturer might require that your product meets AEC standard 12345A.

The nice thing about having an organisation setting the standards is that all car manufacturers can use that same AEC standard 12345A  **if they want that**.

Imagine all car manufacturers having their own standards, you'd have to read them all (provided if you have access to them) and meet all of them. That's a lot of work !

It's much easier when you can say: My product meets AEC standard 12345A

Then everyone knows what we're talking about.

Comment: Unless the car's manufacturer requests it, I can use whatever components I'd like to. It's not like a "CE Mark" type compliance which `allows free movement and sale of the product throughout the European Economic Area` for example.

Comment: *Unless the car's manufacturer requests it, I can use whatever components I'd like to* Exactly !

Answer (score 4):

When I worked for a Tier 4 supplier to Chrysler we made Jeep Cherokee seat heat controllers. Very trivial and simple design but in millions quantity.  Not only did Johnson Controls review the design including qualified parts in the BOM in great detail but they requested  OMRON, the relay supplier to send an engineer to approve our assembly process as well as their own process engineer. Then after passing all these and other ISO standards, they send field engineers to drive a test Jeep up to the Arctic.

Unless things have changed, I would have an "approved" alternate ready and tested with good reasons for your substitution.

Here is an [example](http://www.golledge.com/docs/news/articles/aecq200.htm) of what it means to be qualified for AEC.

> - A round of stringent electrical testing, followed by stress and then a further round of testing to ensure the electrical integrity of
>     the component.
> - The temperature resistance of the part is tested by exposing the samples to the maximum temperature within the required testing range
>     for a prolonged period of time.
> - This is then followed by temperature
>     cycling throughout the entire temperature range, and then a further
>     round of measurement to determine the resistance of the parts.
> - Moisture resistance is tested by exposing the part to a high degree of humidity for a prolonged period of time.
> - The operational life of the component is checked to ensure it passes the required benchmark.
>     -The resistance of the component to solvents is tested.
> - Mechanical shock and vibration resistance are checked by exposing the components to high levels of g-force for prolonged periods oftime, and by cycling the parts through periods of vibration.
> - The solderability of the parts and their resistance to soldering heat is also checked to ensure they are fully operable which involves
>     exposing the components to extremely high temperatures.
> - The board flex and terminal strength of the components are also checked to ensure compliance with standard attachments five and six.
> - Finally the parts undergo a strict visual inspection and a check to ensure their physical characteristics meet the required
>     specifications.